# Display Emote/Image/Emoji in multiline text in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, spannablestring

I am trying to do a chat with emotes. I've discovered that there was InlineTextContent we can use in AnnotedString as an equivalence to SpannableString in XML.

```
inlineContentMap["dragon"] = InlineTextContent(
     Placeholder(32.sp, 32.sp, PlaceholderVerticalAlign.TextCenter) {
                        AsyncImage(
                            model = dragonUrl,
                            contentDescription = null,
                            modifier = Modifier.size(32.dp),
                            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                        )
                    }
)

var annotedString = buildAnnotatedString {
   append("a test with multiline text and an emote"
   appendInlineContent(id = "dragon")
}

Text(
  text = annotatedString,
  inlineContent = inlineContentMap,
  fontSize = 16.sp
)
```

It works pretty well for a single line text or for a multiline text as long as the Image inserted is not bigger than the text size.
In this case there is a difference between SpannableString and InlineTextContent, in SpannableString the lineHeight of the line where the image is inserted will adapt to the image size, while for compose, it currently doesn't:

[image]

I tried then to use the :

```
addStyle(ParagraphStyle(lineHeight = 32.sp), start = 35, end = annotedString.lenght
```

Idea was to change the line where the emote is located to a paragraph with a different lineHeight but it appears that every time i set a paragraphStyle to a line containing an InlineTextContent, it crashes saying i'm over the boundary. While it doesn't if i focus a line when there is not.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                                 

Process: video.joinbits.beta, PID: 21884                                                                                                 

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ParagraphStyle range [40, 46) is out of boundary                                                                                                

at androidx.compose.ui.text.AnnotatedString.<init>(AnnotatedString.kt:70)                                                                                                   

at androidx.compose.ui.text.AnnotatedString$Builder.toAnnotatedString(AnnotatedString.kt:519)
```

I didn't find any mention of this issue, and runs out of idea on how to make it work, any help would be appreciate !

My goal is to have a message displayed like with SpannableString in XML:
[image]

Comment: Could you add the exact stack trace to your question and also clarify exactly what your goal is? It seems like the simple solution would be to make the size of the image consistent so it fits in, but is your goal instead to make the text/spacing larger?

Comment: I added the stack trace, and the goal i'm willing to achieve. If i had to make emote the size of the text it would be to small to really see anything. Basic behavior would be twitch chat where emotes can be bigger than the text, but it only affect the line the emote is in and not all the text. Because i could set a big lineHeight for all the text if it contains an emote, but it takes to much spaces for a 4 lines text it's not suitable. And since the behavior works fine in XML i just want to do the same